# how can i suppress/bypass proxy alert

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, proxy-server

I am using proxy in my code and getting authentication challenge. But before "didReceiveChallenge" get called i am getting alert as shown in below image[image].  If i click "cancel" on the alert than "didReceiveChallenge" is getting invoked.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()

let proxyDict:[String:AnyObject] = [kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable as String: true,
                                    hostKey as String:proxy_server,
                                    portKey as String: proxy_port,
                                    userNameKey as String:userName,
                                    passwordKey as String:password]

config.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in



    print(data)
    print(error)
    print(response)

});

task.resume()


  func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge:     NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler:    (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
let credential = NSURLCredential(user:user, password:password, persistence: .ForSession)
      completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential,credential)
}
```

How can i suppress/bypass the alert which is coming?. Any help is greatly appreciated.